# C - dynamically resizing a 2 dimensional char array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, multidimensional-array

**Hello all you coders, i need your expertise!**

As the headline reveals, i want to resize a 2 dim. char `array` in C. I kind of already know how to do it with ,,simpler" data structures:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void ){
    int *store;
    int capacity = 3;
    store = malloc(capacity * sizeof(int));
    store[0] = 0;
    store[1] = 1;
    store[2] = 2;

    /* need more storage */

    int new_capacity = 5;
    int *more_storage = realloc(store, new_capacity);
    more_storage = store;

    more_storage[3] = 3;
    more_storage[4] = 4;
    // Is this free() command dangerous? 
    free(store);
    /* this for loop gives me the correct integers, so i can proof that more_storage indeed contains all the
    values, that have been stored in store*/
    for (int i = 0; i < new_capacity; i++){
        printf("%d\n", more_storage[i]);
    }

    /* I have succesfully created a new array, that contains all the old integers plus 
    the new ones */ 

    return 0;
}
```

Now let's get to the hot stuff: 
Do the same thing again, only with a char-array, that stores an unknown number of strings with maximum length of 100 (or whatever):

```
char [???][100];
```

Despite the fact that some of you might shake their heads, i post my
approach to it below: (be kind, i'm a c-beginner :P )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void ){
    //this means to be the 2 - dim array. not sure, if i'm wrong yet.
    char *store[100];
    int capacity = 3;
    store[100] = malloc(capacity * 100 * sizeof(char));
    // This (below) already causes a segmentation fault... :/ 
    strcpy(store[0], "Hi");

    /*Okai, im done yet.. */ 



}
```

Here one more approach, might be usefull for your amusement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void ){
    char **store;
    int capacity_words = 3;
    int capacity_letters = 100;
    /* Means: char store[3][100]*/

    store = malloc(capacity_words * capacity_letters *sizeof(char));
    strcpy(store[0], "Hi");
    //Segmentation fault again..
    // Damn..! Programming is hard..:D 

}
```

Okai thats my baseline of knowledge, can anyone share his or her answer with me? :)

(I made his extra detailed and universal because i hope this can serve as answer for any other scholar of the art, too.)

Comment: Your "simpler" example actually won't work, as you have undefined behavior in it. When you do `more_storage = store;` you overwrite the pointer to the new memory with the pointer to the old memory. You should do the *opposite* assignment instead, after checking that `more_storage` isn't `NULL` of course. Then when you're done with the memory you call `free` on `store` (or `more_storage` if you continue to use it).

Comment: well `int *more_storage = realloc(store, new_capacity * sizeof(int));
    /* more_storage = store; <<-- delete this line*/ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition

```
char *store[100];
```

creates an array of 100 pointers to characters. You can assign existing strings to these pointers, maybe strings you got via `strdup`, but you can't `strcpy` to them, because they are uninitialised and don't point anywhere sensible.

You can create a pointer to arrays of 100 chars with:

```
char (*store)[100];
```

Now you can allocate momory to that pointer and use it:

```
int capacity = 3;

store = malloc(capacity * sizeof(*store));
strcpy(store[0], "orange");
strcpy(store[1], "green");
strcpy(store[2], "mauve");
```

Reallocation works likewise:

```
capacity = 5;
store = realloc(store, capacity * sizeof(*store));

store[3] = 3;
store[4] = 4;
```

(I've allocated to new memory to the same space, which is usually what you want. This will lose the original data if the reallocation fails, however. See Joachim's example for how to handle that case.)

Of course you should free the allocated memory after you use it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) puts(store[i]);

free(store);
```

This method may be both wasteful and restrictive, because you waste a lot of space for short strings and are still limited to 99 characters. Allocating memory according to how much you need might be better. (But at least this method gives you 100 chars for each string right away. The only allocation and freeing involved is that of `store` proper.)

Comment: Yes, the tricky bit is declaring the `store` variable with the correct type, which is where @JoschKraus went wrong. There's a program called "cdecl" that can translate C declarations to a more English-like syntax and vice versa, which is great for working out where to put parentheses in your declarations.

Comment: This answer actually solved my problem because you pointed out my syntax error and my missunderstanding of pointer arithmetic. I want to thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Althought i wanna mention, that **store[3] = 3** will not work

Comment: It will. I have reallocated `store` to hold 5 integers. (I have reallocated to the same handle, which is a more likely setup than reallocating to a new handle; you want a bigger array, after all, not a new one. If you do so, you usually only do so temporarily as in Joachim's example. So in this case, I have deviated from your code.)

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use a single-dimension array as a two-dimensional array, but for variable-length data like strings it's more work than it's worth. And if you do then you need a single pointer, not a pointer to pointer.

For strings, instead you need to allocate an array of pointers, like

```
char **store = malloc(initial_size * sizeof(*store));

for (size_t i = 0; i < initial_size; ++i)
    store[i] = some_string;  // alternatively strdup(some_string) or similar
```

Then when you need to reallocate this array, you do it just like you would for a one-dimensional array:

```
char **new_store = realloc(store, new_size * sizeof(*new_store));
if (new_store == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error reallocating memory\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
store = new_store;

for (size_t i = initial_size; i < new_size; ++i)
    store[i] = ...; // Initialize new memory
```

Comment: You gave me quite  a bit of reasonable input, that i will try out and work with! I want to thank you for sharing your knowledge with me and have a nice day Joachim!

Answer (score 2):

code 1) You shouldn't free(store) - it's either already freed by preceeding realloc or equals to new_storage (if realloc decided that old block yet fits new size).

code 2) Array is placed into the stack and it will not have an option to grow without corrupting the stack.

code 3) This is pretty reasonable, but note you should allocate not merely the array itself (outer dimension) but also every inner dimension (capacity_word times a character string). strncpy is not usable here because store[0] isn't yet initialized; instead, try

```
store[0] = strdup("Hi");
store[1] = strdup("There");
store[2] = strdup("!");
```

Comment: AndreyS, you gave me a trace of where to start learing about data initialization and i want to thank you for that!     strdup() (as i have googled) is not always save to use for a beginner, because it is not included in any ISO C standarts. So i will be carefull with that while testing your code. Anyway, thank you for sharing and have a nice day!